# PHP MySQL Double submit using two SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webshop, user will buy something 
When the user visit the my web, their data will be saved temporarly in a variable $user as an array
It will be checked when the user buy something, if their balance is more or equal to the things that they want to buy, but the problem arise when there are some users that try to use two browsers to buy things at the same times, their balance just cut once (it should be twice, since they buy it twice using two browsers)

I know I can just update the $user variable before checking, but I will have to run another query to MySQL, and there is many orders ...

Is there any SQL syntax that can be used to prevent this kind of attack?
for checking their balance and make sure it's correct

Comment: No. You have to make the correct checks with persisted data if you want the correct answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly so there is no other ways beside updating the variable before processing the order ... oke ... thanks

Comment: If the only place where the data is guaranteed to be correct you have to look for the data there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on your current setup (ie using a variable):**

Someone using two browser on the same site trying to use up their balance is going to be fairly rare, with most cases someone trying to game your system.

Just finally check their balance at the point of processing the order and if ok allow it, otherwise don't. For those doing it by accident (which is rare), they'll soon realise the error.

**An alternative:**

It'd be better to check the real data rather than a variable which isn't reliable and has to be forced to be persistent, and as you know not available in different sessions.

I think a better way would be to use some fast centralised persistent storage like Redis (fairly easy to learn, *essentially* it's an array stored in memory). You can then store their username (or whatever uniquely IDs them) and while they may have different keys across the two browsers, there will be a common unique ID and you can update their credit value in both (all) sessions by searching for the unique ID.

Then whatever browser that user is logged in to will be updated same as other browsers.

**Maybe a better idea:**
Unless your application needs it, don't let people log in to different browsers/devices. When they try to login, state "already logged in on another place, want to log that one our and log in here?" etc